# how to use lwm?

Tags: window-manager, window

I'm an ubuntu-gnome user and my system has 4Gs of ram. So it's really difficult for me to work on android studio. Someone recommended that I use lwm(lightweight window manager). I installed it and it added an entry to the login screen. But it turned out that it's really very very lightweight. When I login to lwm, I'm greeted with a black screen with a pointer, and nothing else. The pointer works, but there is nothing to point to. Keyboard doesn't do anything. The [home page](http://www.jfc.org.uk/software/lwm.html) of lwm doesn't help very much. It describes various cl options to be given to it. When I execute `lwm` on a terminal it says `another window manager is already running.`.Maybe it needs some other programs to work correctly. Anybody knows anything about it?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the desktop: does a program menu come up?

Comment: Ok I'll try it. I'm not familiar with anything like this. The blank screen looked like the initial loading screen of unity to me.;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make an Answer for this question, quoting from the online [lwm man page](http://www.jfc.org.uk/software/lwm-stable.1x.html):

> Lwm is a window manager for the X Window System. It provides enough
>   features to allow the user to manage their windows, and no more.
>   Windows are surrounded by a frame with a titlebar at the top next to a
>   small box. The frame is a grey colour for all windows except that
>   which has the input focus, where it is black.
>
> In the default configuration, lwm uses the enter-to-focus scheme,
>   where moving the pointer into a window gives that window the input
>   focus. Lwm may also be configured to use the click-to-focus scheme,
>   where a window must be clicked on (with any button) to receive the
>   input focus. Clicking on a window in this mode causes the window to be
>   raised. Note that a click used to focus a window is always swallowed
>   by lwm, so clicking a button in a new window requires two clicks.
>
> A button 1 click on a window frame brings that window to the top.
>   Dragging button 1 on the frame of a resizable window repositions that
>   edge of the window. If a corner rather than an edge is dragged, then
>   both edges forming the corner are repositioned. While you're reshaping
>   a window, a little window pops up to show you the window's current
>   size.
>
> In the default configuration, button 1 on the root window does
>   nothing.
>
> Button 2 is used to drag a window by its frame, repositioning the
>   window but maintaining its position in the window stack.
>
> In the default configuration, button 2 on the root window brings up a
>   new shell.
>
> A button 3 click on a window frame hides that window. Pressing button
>   3 on the root window brings up a menu. The various items unhide the
>   named hidden window.
>
> A button 3 click in the frame while Shift is held down pushes the
>   window to the back, under any other windows. (Users with 4-button mice
>   are encouraged to use their fourth button for this function.)
>
> A click with any button inside the little white box in a window's
>   frame can be used to close the window.